# Manager field in SharePoint 2016 is not synced using Microsoft Identity Manager

Tags: user-profile-service

We have installed Microsoft Identity Manager and performed all the steps to sync MIM with Sharepoint, but what we noticed is that Manager field in SharePoint 2016 User profile is not synced, rather it is empty while in AD and in MIM it contains a value.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -eq 'User Profile Service Application'}
$sa.NoILMUsed = $true
$sa.Update()
```

Ref: [Additional PowerShell Required for Microsoft Identity Manager](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/05/additional-powershell-required-for-mim/)

EDIT: This is no longer necessary with the Feb 2017 PU, although manual fixes are required and outlined at https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/02/microsoft-identity-manager-noilmused-bug-fixed/. The fix boils down to, post-install/Config Wizard, running:

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -match 'Profile'}
$sa.Provision()
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for your response. Do you think that this will help me with photos as well as some of the photos are not synced.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. You'll want to use the MIM console to identify users who aren't correctly syncing photos and see if the photos made it into the metaverse as well as to the SPMA.

Comment: Trevor, how do I access MIM console?

Comment: It's on your MIM server located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager\2010\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe`. It will also be in your start menu labeled 'Synchronization Service' with a green icon.

Comment: Ok, I knew about the 'Sychronization Service' green icon, but I thought the console was a something different. Some of the photos have made in metaverse and some not. There are users who do not have an attribute photos in when I check the properties in metaverse. How can this be? Now, I don't know how to check if the photos have made in the SPMA. The only way I know so far is by syncing the photos and looking in my sites.

Answer (score 0):

Because I just signed in here, I can't comment to the answer above but I think it's important to clarify the use of NoILMUsed property.

Setting NoILMUsed to $true will basically set the Configure Synchronization Settings to Use SharePoint Active Directory Import. But on this case, and I'm facing the same error currently, we are using MIM what is an External Identity Manager. So, we don't want to keep NOILMUSed setting in true.

I did use the following version that will set the sync setting back to external but this didn't have the right effect.

```
$upsa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -eq 'User Profile Service Application'}

$upsa.NoILMUsed = $true
$upsa.Update()
$upsa.NoILMUsed = $false
$upsa.Update()

& {iisreset}
```

Still trying to find the solution.

Comment: `NoILMUsed` needs to be set when using MIM. Leave it set to true.

Comment: How can you leave the NoILMUsed setting to true if you want to use MIM?

If you want to use MIM, you should set the Configure Synchronization Settings to Enable External Identity Manager. When you set this the NoILMUsed is set as False automatically.

Comment: No, you for now must set it to true. This is due to a *bug* in the implementation. I've done this for many implementations and this information comes from the SharePoint PG directly.

Comment: Setting it to true will mean that you are actually using AD Import, not external service like MIM, correct?

Can you still run the MIM behind the scenes even if the NoILMUsed is true and you are using AD Import?

AD Import is missing some of the features MIM will offer, like synchronization back to AD and some custom properties. This is the reason why I'm using MIM in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say at this point. It's a bug in the product when using MIM, MIM is still used, it still functions, and it fixes the issues with importing the `manager` attribute as well as Audiences based on Active Directory attributes and/or groups.

Comment: Official statement is at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2624198/support-policy-regarding-use-of-noilmused-property

Comment: And this has now been fixed in the Feb 2017 PU, however the job doesn't install correctly. I've provided additional instructions at https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/02/microsoft-identity-manager-noilmused-bug-fixed/.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't comment to above answer threads, but let me state this. I have exactly the same issues like Helm and MikkoK. I'm pretty sure I configured everything correctly - in multiple environments and I just can't get the manager field populated in SharePoint. Even MIM says the export to SharePoint is successful. Then I also found [this](https://vigneshsharepointthoughts.com/2015/12/24/sharepoint-2013-external-fim-issue-missing-manager-property/) and really thought: "Cool, that's a solution." It isn't! It's basically the same that MikkoK posted here, but it doesn't help. I tried it with both NoILMUsed set to true and to false but none of it worked.

So, what else can we try? One sentence is very interesting in my mentioned link. It says:

> What this means is that we’re getting a null reference exception, when the FIM management agent/connector for SharePoint finishes up. It calls a finalize method that’s part of the web service. This finalize method is checking for a running instance of the “User Profile AD Import Timer Job “. The problem is that this timer job only gets created if your UPSA configuration settings is set to use the “Active Directory Import” option. Please check the screenshot below.

So, no matter, what we do, I'd bet there's a problem with the "SharePoint internal finalization" of the manager field import. By the way: I also created another field in the SharePoint User Profile Service of type person and tried to sync the manager attribute with that one - same "success". MIM is doing everything well, but attribute is not populated to SharePoint User Profile.

If someone has another ideas or even a working solution for this I'd really appreciate this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and installed the March 2017 update and it got resolved.

Comment: This section is to provide workaround or solutions to problems and hence called as Answer Section..You are not supposed to post comments, thanks ,same issues on this section.